# IntelliJ fails on every test on a maven imported project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng

I imported a maven project to intellij with two modules under a parent project.
The test I want to run is made with TestNg and when I run it I just get a single line of:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

No stacktrace, nothing.

If I run it from the command line it works, but only if I cd into the directory of one of the modules.
So basically thats the command that actually works:

```
cd server
mvn -Dtest=ConversionServiceT2 test
```

I'm pretty sure I didn't configure IntelliJ in the right way, but I have no idea where to start.
Here a few infos that might help:

- I use the openJDK 11
- I tried to set the working directory of the test config in IntelliJ to the server directory, which results in the same error

So how can I get this test (or tests in general) to run?

Comment: Have you tried setting the working directory in the Intellij Run/Debug Configuration?

Comment: "Thank you in advance." and similar taglines are frowned upon by a majority of stackoverflow users, see here for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @PiRocks yes I did, it didn't change the output unfortunatelly. 
 I removed it, thanks

Comment: Often intelij shows the command it ran in the console. Is this the case for you, and if show what did it run exactly?

Comment: It doesnt show anything...

Comment: Go to the module where the test placed and open the pom xml, find project directory property. Check if server directory is in the path. If you don't have project directory property you can add it.

Comment: Please add the project structure with the sub modules to help you out. Maybe you need to concatinate server package to sub module tag.